# Sound lost from HDMI out when no screen connected

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

My Intel Computestick (with Ubuntu 14.04) is connected to my Marantz AV Surround Receiver SR7009, which in turn is connected to my projector. If I start the computestick with the projector is off, the sound works for a few minutes and then dissapears.

When starting:

```
selitakis@computestick:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: IntelHDMI [IntelHDMI], device 0: IntelHDMI [IntelHDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

After a while when the sound dissapears:

```
selitakis@computestick:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: IntelHDMI [IntelHDMI], device 0: IntelHDMI [IntelHDMI]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've looked at the other questions when people do not get any sound through hdmi, but I haven't found any examples where people get sound and then lose it.